# What is the best way to create a mobile web service API?

Tags: android

i am new to android programming and i want to create an api with a login system and a whole set of different API calls.  what is the most common convention on doing this for mobile apps? thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the services in any server side language that you like, i personally would do it in Ruby or php, but you could use Java, python, or any other language you like

Comment: okay sweet that sounds good. is there a framework specific for web services in ruby that you can recommend?

Comment: Ruby on rails all the way! :)